# Does akka streams use a work pulling model under the covers?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

How does akka streams work under the covers?

It is essentially a work pulling (http://www.michaelpollmeier.com/akka-work-pulling-pattern) but maybe have multiple steps to the work pulling mechanism?

Can someone point me to the source code where I can get an idea how it does this, or is it too complex underneath the covers? :)

Comment: I don't know how it actually works, but consider the existence of this: https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-stream/src/main/scala/akka/stream/OverflowStrategy.scala I'm going to guess that no, it doesn't use work pulling.

Comment: AFAIK akka-streams is an implementation of http://www.reactive-streams.org/ which uses a model where the subscriber tells the publisher when it's allowed to push (so I guess technically a push model).

Answer (score 1):

Akka Streams implements [Reactive Streams](http://www.reactive-streams.org). The idea is that you have "backpressure" in your stream, so the consumer can signal its demand to the producer. This results in "dynamic push-pull":

If the consumer is slower than the producer, it's "pull".

If the producer is slower than the consumer, it's "push".

See http://www.slideshare.net/rolandkuhn/reactive-streams for more information.